# Revert svn update to previous BASE revision

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Let's say I made a svn update in a entire directory by accident.
How do I revert it to its previous state? I could revert to the previous revision, the problem is that I don't know the number of this revision (and svn doesnt tell me what revision I am updating from, it only says "Updated to revision XXXX").

Answer (score 0):

Your working copy could be in mixed revision state before you updated it (i.e. files could be at different revisions). I don't know how to revert to this particular state unless you noted it down or tagged your working copy's state.

Comment: Files have different revisions but SVN does know the highest revision in the local project, which is, the BASE revision. It seems trivial for svn to note down this number to allow for a rollback.